# How to troubleshoot issues caused by clustering or load balancing?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Hi I have a application that is deploy on two weblogic app servers

recently we have issue that for certain cases the user session returned is null. Developer feedback is that it could be caused by the session not replicating to the other server.

How do we prove if this is really the case?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a single session store that both application servers can access via some communication protocol?  If not, then it is definitely the case.  Think about it, if your weblogic servers are storing the session in memory anywhere, and having users pass their session id via cookies, than the other server has no way of accessing the memory on the other machine.  Unless you are using sticky load balancing.  Are you?

Comment: How do we know if the load balance is session sticky?

Comment: Are you using software or hardware based load balancer?  Who set it up? They should know if it is sticky or not sticky.

Comment: A quick and dirty way of telling is to have the server respond to all requests with a header that has its machine name in it.  Then issue 60 requests or so through an http proxy and inspect those headers.  If it's always the same machine then the load balancing is sticky.  If it changes machines, it's not.

Comment: Seens to be hardware balancer. I ambtold that the session is sticky

Comment: You many want to test in the way I described above to see if they are accurate. If it does indeed appear to be sticky, then I would get more information from your developers in regards to what series of actions leads to returning a null user session, even if it appears to be random to them.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 concepts to consider here - Session stickiness and session replication.

Session Stickiness is a mechanism where weblogic server ensures that if a request from a user with session A goes to server 1 then the next request from user with session A will go to server 1 only.

This is achieved by configuring a hardware loadbalancer (like F5) which is capable of providing session stickiness. or configuring weblogic proxy installed on apache/iis/weblogic.

The first time a request reached WLS managed server, it responds with a session id and appends to it the JVM id of the server (this is the primary id), if the managed server is part of a cluster, it also attaches a secondary server jvm id (the secondary server is the server where the session is being replicated)

The proxy maintains a table of all JVM id's and corresponding IP of managed server, it also checks periodically if the servers are up and running or not.

The next time when another request passes the proxy with existing session id and a primary jvm id, the proxy parses this and tries to send the request to that server, if it cannot within some time it tries to send to secondary server.

Session Replication - This is enabled by default when you configure a WLS cluster with 2 or more managed server. Each time any data is updates to a session, its data is replication in a secondary server too.

So in your case if your application users are loosing session or getting redirected to login page between normal usage, then check that the session did not get invalidated because of a timeout, if you have defined a cluster and using WLS proxy then check the proxy debug output to make sure the primary and secondary server are being appended to the session id.

Finally there's a simple example in the sample application deployment of wls that you can use to test session replication and failover functionality.

So to prove why session is getting lost, 
1) check server log to see if session got invalidated because of timeout,
2) if using wlproxy, enable debug, and the next time the issue happens check in the proxy log if the request was sent to a different server, and if that server is not the secondary server.